# Webservice error 400 while using Docusign API in php

Tags: php, docusignapi

Hello friends I am using an HTTP server to access Doucsign. And I am getting server problem
That is server error 400 and errorCode.

> INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS_FOR_RECIPIENT", "message": "The email address
>   for the recipient is invalid. The recipient Id follows.

My code is

```
<?php

// Input your info here:
$email = "****";            // your account email
$password = "*******";      // your account password
$integratorKey = "*********";       // your account integrator key, found on  (Preferences -> API page)
$recipientName = "usa usa";     // provide a recipient (signer) name
$documentName = "proposal.pdf";     // copy document with same name into this directory!

// construct the authentication header:
$header = "<DocuSignCredentials><Username>" . $email . "</Username><Password>" . $password . "</Password><IntegratorKey>" . $integratorKey . "</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 1 - Login (to retrieve baseUrl and accountId)
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
$url = "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/login_information";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ( $status != 200 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$accountId = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["accountId"];
$baseUrl = $response["loginAccounts"][0]["baseUrl"];
curl_close($curl);

//--- display results
echo "\naccountId = " . $accountId . "\nbaseUrl = " . $baseUrl . "\n";

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// STEP 2 - Create an envelope with one recipient, one tab, and one document and send
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// the following request body will place 1 signature tab on the document you supply, located
// 100 pixels to the right and 100 pixels down from the top left of the document
$data = array (
        "emailSubject" => "DocuSign API - Signature Request on Document",
        "documents" => array( array( "documentId" => "1", "name" => $documentName)),
        "recipients" => array( "signers" => array(
            array(  "email" => $email,
                   "name" => $recipientName,
                    "recipientId" => "1",
                    "tabs" => array(
                        "signHereTabs" => array(
                            array( "xPosition" => "100",
                                   "yPosition" => "100",
                                   "documentId" => "1",
                                   "pageNumber" => "1" )
                        ))
             ))
        ),
    "status" => "sent"
);
$data_string = json_encode($data);  

$file_contents = file_get_contents($documentName);

$requestBody = "\r\n"
."\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: form-data\r\n"
."\r\n"
."$data_string\r\n"
."--myboundary\r\n"
."Content-Type:application/pdf\r\n"
."Content-Disposition: file; filename=\"$documentName\"; documentid=1 \r\n"
."\r\n"
."$file_contents\r\n"
."--myboundary--\r\n"
."\r\n";

// *** append "/envelopes" to baseUrl and as signature request endpoint
$curl = curl_init($baseUrl . "/envelopes" );
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $requestBody); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(                                                                          
    'Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=myboundary',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($requestBody),
    "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )                                                                       
);



$json_response = curl_exec($curl);
$status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
echo $status;
if ( $status != 201 ) {
    echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status . "\nerror text is --> ";
    print_r($json_response); echo "\n";
    exit(-1);
}

$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
$envelopeId = $response["envelopeId"];

//--- display results
echo "Document is sent! Envelope ID = " . $envelopeId . "\n\n";
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `$email` a valid email address?